# Observing count in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I'd like to be notified, when the count, ie. number of items in an NSArray changes..
Of course I wouldn't need this, if I was in control of addition and removal of objects into the array. But I am not, it happens unpredictably  with regards to Business Process Model and depends on external factors.
Is there some simple elegant solution?

EDIT: I am correcting this to NSMutableArray of course..

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but a keyPath to an array and the suffix `@count` is the KVC way to get this value. So perhaps you can KVO observe `array@count`? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 15):

You’ll need to use [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).  But how to go about doing it?  After all, NSMutableArray is not Key-Value-Coding compliant for its mutation methods or contents changes.  The answer is proxying –as subclassing NS[Mutable]Array is far too much of a hassle.

NSProxy is a great little class that you can use to intercept the messages sent to your array as though you were an NSMutableArray, then forward them on to some internal instance.  Unfortunately, it is also not KVC compliant, as the guts of KVC live in NSObject.  We’ll have to use that, then.  A sample interface might look something like this:

```
@interface CFIKVCMutableArrayProxy : NSObject  {
    NSMutableArray *_innerArray;
}

- (NSUInteger)count;

- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject;
- (void)removeLastObject;
- (void)insertObjects:(NSArray *)objects atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;

//…

@end
```

As you can see, we’re simulating an interface for `NSMutableArray`, which is necessary, as our proxy should implement everything as though it were an `NSMutableArray`.  This also makes the implementation as simple as possible, as we can just forward the selectors on to our inner `NSMutableArray` pointer.  For the sake of brevity, I’ll only implement two methods to show you what a general outline looks like:

```
@implementation CFIKVCMutableArrayProxy

//…

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return _innerArray.count;
}

- (void)addObject:(id)anObject {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"count"];
    [_innerArray addObject:anObject];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"count"];
}

- (void)removeLastObject {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"count"];
    [_innerArray removeLastObject];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"count"];
}

@end
```

If you have no opportunities to wrap an array like this, then try to re-think your code.  If an external dependency is forcing you into this kind of corner, try to remove it.  It’s always a bad thing to work around your own tools.

Comment: Some time has passed and a fortunate improvement will be implemented on the part of code that is out of my control - the facade object that holds the array will now issue NSNotifications when the model changes.

Your proposed solution is noteworthy however you missed the little but important fact that I wasn't in control of the array. So it was not possible for me to inject the proxy object to the facade instead of array.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 7):

To observe changes in a mutableArray one needs to use mutable proxy object given by

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key
```

which is KVO compliant, i.e. any change of proxy object sends will/did change notifications.

The following demo class shown the full implementation

```
@interface DemoClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;

- (void)addItemsObserver:(id)object;
- (void)removeItemsObserver:(id)object;

@end

@implementation DemoClass

- (NSMutableArray *)items;
{
    return [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"_items"];
}

- (void)addItemsObserver:(id)object
{
    [self addObserver:object forKeyPath:@"_items.@count" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)removeItemsObserver:(id)object
{
    [self removeObserver:object forKeyPath:@"_items.@count" context:nil];
}
@end


@interface ObservingClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) DemoClass *demoObject;

@end

@implementation ObservingClass

- (instanstype)init
{
     if (self = [super init]) {
         _demoObject = [DemoClass new];

         [_demoObject addItemsObserver:self];
     }
     return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
     NSLog(@"is called on demoObject.items.count change");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_demoObject removeItemsObserver:self];
}

@end
```

Now every time you add or remove an object in the `items` you'll see new log in console (`observeValueForKeyPath` is called).

Any direct change of auto-synthesised ivar `_items`array will have no effect.

Also note that you strongly need to set the observer on `_items.@count` (observing `items.@count` is senseless).

Note that you needn't to init `_items` or `self.items`. It will be done behind the scene when you call `items` getter.

Every time you change the "array" `items` you will get new object `_items` with new address. But I can still find it via `items` proxy getter.

Comment: You may want a `removeProxyItemsObserver:` method as well.

Comment: @AaronBrager, just added for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: Why not add the use of mutableArrayValueForKey to your sample code which is the important bit!